# Yii2: validation rule for array?

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I can define a rule for a single integer like this:

```
[['x'], 'integer']
```

Is it possible to tell that x is an integer array? For example:

```
[['x'], 'integer[]']
```

And could I specify the valid values in the array?

**Update**: From Yii version 2.0.4 we've got some help. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252934/yii2-validation-rule-for-array/30300977#30300977).

Comment: Is this for model rules? You can't really store an array, maybe a serialization of it. Do you wanna try to make yourself a bit clearer?

Comment: In my case it is model for a form that contains some checkboxes that are loaded as an array (with $modal->load(Yii::$app->request->post()). So it is not for an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: @Chen Asraf You can store an array if you use **mongodb**

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From version 2.0.4 there is the new [EachValidator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md#yiivalidatorseachvalidatoreach-) which makes it more easy now:

```
['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
```

This should be sufficient. If the values should be also checked you could use this (with the ['in' validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#in) which actually is the RangeValidator):

```
['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['in', 'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8]]], // each value in x can only be 2, 4, 6 or 8
```

However, you can use this 'in' validator also directly. And that is possible with Yii versions before 2.0.4:

```
['x', 'in', 'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8], 'allowArray' => true]
```

The use of `'strict' => true` would probably makes no sense in case the data is sent by the client and is set with [Model->load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load%28%29-detail). I'm not quite sure but I think those values are all sent as strings (like "5" instead of 5).

Comment: ['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['in', 'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8]]] will not work if x is an array  of ints (not a scalar type). It should be done like you described below ['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['in', 'allowArray' => true, 'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8]]]. I've spent some time while I defined where exactly I'm doing something wrong. Nevertheless thanks for your answer

Comment: ['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']] I am using this exact line in my SearchModel but it doesn't work... It seems to ignore the rule... Why?

Comment: @webpaul Hard to say. Create a new question with detailed information.

Answer (score 18):

You may need to create custom validation rules like below:

```
['x','checkIsArray']
```

Then in your model, impelement `checkIsArray`:

```
public function checkIsArray(){
     if(!is_array($this->x)){
         $this->addError('x','X is not array!');
     }
}
```

You can do all you need into a custom validation rule.

---

As *emte* mentioned on comment, you can also use inline validator with anonymous function like below:

```
['x',function ($attribute, $params) {
    if(!is_array($this->x)){
         $this->addError('x','X is not array!');
     }
}]
```

Comment: This sounds reasonably!

Comment: if you don't want to specify new function, you can use anonymouse  function directly in the rule

Comment: It is better to use `is_array($this->$attribute)`. This useful if you have several attributes in this rule.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to check against specific range for each array element

```
['x', 'required']
```

plus

```
['x', 'each', 'rule' => ['in',  'allowArray' => true, 'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8]]]
```

or

```
['x', 'in', 'allowArray' => true,  'range' => [2, 4, 6, 8] ]
```