# Passing multi-dimensional array within Yii2 validation rules?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When you are using Yii2's validation rules within a model, for example:

```
[['foo','bar'], 'integer],
```

Obviously `['foo','bar']` is an array, which I know you can use.

But can do pass a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
$this->numbers = [1,2,3];

[['foo','bar','numbers'], 'integer]
```

Will Yii2 accept this and check the correct data or will it test the value and return an error because `numbers` is an array?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30300977/57091) will help you, if you want to create a validation with certain allowed values. Do you mean foo and bar may only have value 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: Or numbers should be an integer array? Yes, that needs to be defined separately from foo and bar if these attributes are 'normal' integers.

Comment: @robsch Yep, the second one. I have moved them to using the `each` validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need merge arrays for work rules

```
[ArrayHelper::merge(['foo','bar'], $this->getNumberFields()), 'integer']
```

Update:

Use `each` rule. See [EachValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator.html).

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['numbers', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is `$this->getNumberFields()`?

Comment: Function in your model that return field names array like `['dynamicIntegerFieldOne', 'integerFieldTwo']`.

Comment: But I would just want to pass it the property name Like I do with `foo` & `bar`. I guess I was just checking if it could all be done within the one rule, if not I will just use the `each` validator on a second rule. :)

Comment: @Brett `[ArrayHelper::merge(['foo','bar'], $this->numbers), 'integer']` could work. The rule will always be re-created when validation takes place. So `$this->numbers` can change from one to the next validation, if this is important.

Comment: @robsch So why would you use `$this->numbers` rather than just `numbers` - aren't you supposed to provide the property name and not it's value?

Comment: @Brett Not sure what you mean. If you do the merge integer validations would be done for 5 attributes: foo, bar, dog, cat, fish. Those attributes should have integer values. They don't need to be explicitly declared, but they would be expected to exist when validation takes place. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, my fault for not being clear enough. `numbers` is the example attribute name which contains an *array* of values. Sorry for making it seem like it was an array of property names, I have updated my post.

Comment: @brett Yii2 will get error. If rule integer, therefore numbers should be integer. You need `each` rule.