# How to validate two dimensional array in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to validate two dimensional array in Yii2.

```
 passenger[0][name] = bell
 passenger[0][email] = myemail@test.com
 passenger[1][name] = carson123
 passenger[1][email] = carson##@test.com
```

how to validate the name and email in this array

Thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @Yupik will you help me

Comment: Try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808190/passing-multi-dimensional-array-within-yii2-validation-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808190/passing-multi-dimensional-array-within-yii2-validation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most clean solution for validating 2-dimensional array is treating this as array of models. So each array with set of `email` and `name` data should be validated separately.

```
class Passenger extends ActiveRecord {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['email', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['email'], 'email'],
        ];
    }
}

class PassengersForm extends Model {

    /**
     * @var Passenger[]
     */
    private $passengersModels = [];

    public function loadPassengersData($passengersData) {
        $this->passengersModels = [];
        foreach ($passengersData as $passengerData) {
            $model = new Passenger();
            $model->setAttributes($passengerData);
            $this->passengersModels[] = $model;
        }

        return !empty($this->passengers);
    }

    public function validatePassengers() {
        foreach ($this->passengersModels as $passenger) {
            if (!$passenger->validate()) {
                $this->addErrors($passenger->getErrors());
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
$model = new PassengersForm();
$model->loadPassengersData(\Yii::$app->request->post('passenger', []));
$isValid = $model->validatePassengers();
```

You may also use [`DynamicModel`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel) instead of creating `Passanger` model if you're using it only for validation.

---

Alternatively you could just create [your own validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#creating-validators) and use it for each element of array:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['passengers'], 'each', 'rule' => [PassengerDataValidator::class]],
    ];
}
```

You may also want to read [Collecting tabular input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input) section in guide (unfortunately it is still incomplete).